# Do Tor Browser updates happen through Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, update, speed

I noticed Tor Browser updates were really fast, while overall connection speed was more Tor-like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does download through Tor. See the [Tor Browser Design Document](https://2019.www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#update-safety).

> We make use of the Firefox updater in order to provide automatic
> updates to users. We make use of certificate pinning to ensure that
> update checks cannot be tampered with by setting
> security.cert_pinning.enforcement_level to 2, and we sign the
> individual MAR update files with keys that get rotated every year.
>
> The Firefox updater also has code to ensure that it can reliably
> access the update server to prevent availability attacks, and
> complains to the user after 48 hours go by without a successful
> response from the server. **Additionally, we use Tor's SOCKS username
> and password isolation to ensure that every new request to the updater
> (provided the former got issued more than 10 minutes ago) traverses a
> separate circuit, to avoid holdback attacks by exit nodes**.